# How to align vertically nav content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have buttons in my page navigation part. Buttons are in unorder list tag such that:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse noPadding">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header logo"></div>
            <ul class=" nav navbar-left navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#" class="link_btn_clickable_padding"><button class="btn btn-danger btn_no_border">هشدارها</button></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="link_btn_clickable_padding"><button class="btn btn-success btn_no_border">اقلام جدید</button></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="link_btn_clickable_padding"><button class="btn btn-primary btn_no_border">ناموجود</button></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="link_btn_clickable_padding"><button class="btn btn-info btn_no_border">مشتریان جدید</button></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="link_btn_clickable_padding"><button class="btn btn-warning btn_no_border">همکاران جدید</button></a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle link_btn_clickable_padding" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><button class="btn-default btn_no_border navbar-btn">سهیل<span class="caret"></span></button></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">نمایه</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">خروج</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

and I want to align buttons vertically in navigation part.
How can I do that?
https://jsfiddle.net/wzh68cad/2/

I put border in `ul` area and I want the `ul` area be aligned vertically, I mean top and bottom distance should be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CHANGED ANSWER ONCE MORE AFTER COMMENT

You can use flexbox. Just add this:

```
nav .container-fluid {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.navbar-header.logo {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tzees3oh/5/

Comment: `float: none;` make list vertical but I want my list to be inline and align vertically in `ul` parent

Comment: By vertically align I mean distance from top and button should be the same, but list items are in a line

Comment: I put a border in `ul` area and I want the ul `area` be aligned vertically, I mean top and bottom distance should be the same. https://jsfiddle.net/wzh68cad/2/

Comment: What you are talking about is "vertically center-aligned"... Note my once-more changed answer

Comment: Thanks, I've text `nav  ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}` but it didn't work. why?

Comment: I don't know - must be some additional code that causes it which is not in the fiddle.

Comment: this solution help but my `ul` content used to be on the left side using class `navbar-left`, but now `ul` content aren't on the left. If I use `float:left;` it works but all of my nav content go to the left! How can I solve this part?

Comment: it is on the left part (see my fiddle), there is just some space for a logo that isn't there.

Comment: then add `justify-content: flex-end;` to the rule for the container - https://jsfiddle.net/tzees3oh/4/

Comment: I also added `margin-right: auto;` for the logo now, so that it is left-aligned.

Comment: thanks, see this link https://jsfiddle.net/wzh68cad/3/, I want my logo `div` put in opposite side of `ul`. For example `logo` on the right and `ul` on the left.but now, as is shown on the link, both of them are in the same side!

Comment: above you wrote that you want your nav to align right which I showed you. I also showed you in my answer and my previous comment how to put the logo on the opposite side. Now you want everything the other way round - do you want to kid me? If you look at my answer and comments and think about how it works you should be able to do it whatever way you want.

Comment: I'm appreciated for your help. Base on your answer all of the navbar align on one side, but I want `ul` part and `logo` part to be on opposite way.Sth like `navbar-left` or `navbar-right` class in bootstrap but because we use `flex` those two class didn;t work!

Answer (score 0):

Set width if you need to vertically align them of equal width

```css
.btn {
  width: 100px; //or whatever width/units you like that fits everything
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse noPadding">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header"></div>
    <ul class=" nav navbar-left navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#" class="link_btn_clickable_padding"><button class="btn btn-danger btn_no_border">هشدارها</button></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="link_btn_clickable_padding"><button class="btn btn-success btn_no_border">اقلام جدید</button></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="link_btn_clickable_padding"><button class="btn btn-primary btn_no_border">ناموجود</button></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="link_btn_clickable_padding"><button class="btn btn-info btn_no_border">مشتریان جدید</button></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="link_btn_clickable_padding"><button class="btn btn-warning btn_no_border">همکاران جدید</button></a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle link_btn_clickable_padding" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><button class="btn-default btn_no_border navbar-btn">سهیل<span class="caret"></span></button></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">نمایه</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">خروج</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: @ahoora: Do you want to align items with equal width.

Comment: I have a logo on nav-header class and this part make navbar higher and buttons are not align vertically

Comment: By vertically align I mean distance from top and button should be the same, but list items are in a line